# Flume is not picking my JMS binding file

Tags: jms, jndi, flume, flume-ng

I am trying to set up a flume agent that uses JMS as the source and HDFS as the sink.

The steps I have followed are

1) Created a .binding file by

```

```
git clone https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-docker.git

docker volume create qm1data

docker run \
  --env LICENSE=accept \
  --env MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1 \
  --publish 1414:1414 \
  --publish 9443:9443 \
  --volume mqvol:/tmp/mq --detach mq
```

go to /opt/mqm/java/bin/JMSAdmin ->

```
DEFINE QCF(confact) QMGR(QM1) tran(client) chan(DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN) host(10.2.201.80) port(1414)
DEFINE Q(DEV.QUEUE.1) QUEUE(DEV.QUEUE.1) QMGR(QM1)
end
```

```

2) drop the related jars and .binding file in place using the following helpful link [how to use .binding file for JMS to HDFS](http://wpcertification.blogspot.ca/2015/08/configure-flume-to-use-ibm-mq-as-jms.html)

3) Start flume agent only to get the following error message

```
org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Could not lookup ConnectionFactory
    at org.apache.flume.source.jms.JMSSource.doConfigure(JMSSource.java:233)
    at org.apache.flume.source.BasicSourceSemantics.configure(BasicSourceSemantics.java:65)
    at org.apache.flume.source.AbstractPollableSource.configure(AbstractPollableSource.java:65)
    at org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:326)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:101)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:141)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: confact
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.getObjectFromBindings(RefFSContext.java:400)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookupObject(RefFSContext.java:327)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookup(RefFSContext.java:146)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.lookup(FSContext.java:127)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at org.apache.flume.source.jms.JMSSource.doConfigure(JMSSource.java:231)
```

where `confact` is the factory i created.

The binding file looks similar to

```
cat /var/lib/flume-ng/plugins.d/ibmmqjms/jndi/.binding|head -10
#This file is used by the JNDI FSContext.
#Sun Feb 18 13:41:26 UTC 2018
confact/RefAddr/30/Encoding=String
confact/RefAddr/19/Content=unspecified
confact/RefAddr/26/Content=1
confact/RefAddr/33/Content=0
confact/RefAddr/70/Content=443
confact/RefAddr/15/Content=false
confact/RefAddr/22/Content=1
confact/RefAddr/102/Type=XMSC_CONNECTION_TYPE
```

I am suspecting that the JNDI binding is not happening because of some reason.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
..Manas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the binding file name should be called `.bindings` instead of `.binding`